# Tictactoe JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, dom-events

Javascript:

```
let grid = [
    [null, null, null],
    [null, null, null],
    [null, null, null]
];


// Assuming Player 1 starts.
let turn = "Player_1";

function checkRows() {
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        if (grid[i][0] === grid[i+1][1] && grid[i][0] === grid[i+1][2] && grid[i][0] !== null) {
            alert(grid[i][0] === 'X' ? 'Player 1 wins!' : 'Player 2 wins!');
        }
            console.log(grid[i][0] === grid[i+1][1] && grid[i][0] === grid[i+1][2] && grid[i][0] !== null);
    }
}

function checkColumns() {
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        if (grid[0][i] === grid[2][i] && grid[0][i] === grid[2][i] && grid[0][i] !== null) {
            alert(grid[0][i] === 'X' ? 'Player 1 wins!' : 'Player 2 wins!');
        }
        console.log(grid[0][i] === grid[2][i] && grid[0][i] === grid[2][i] && grid[0][i] !== null)
    }
}

function checkDiagonals() {
    if (grid[0][0] === grid[1][1] && grid[0][0] === grid[2][2] && grid[0][0] !== null) {
        alert(grid[1][1] === 'X' ? 'Player 1 wins!' : 'Player 2 wins!');
    }
        console.log(grid[0][0] === grid[1][1] && grid[0][0] === grid[2][2] && grid[0][0] !== null)
}

function checkWinningPositions() {
    this.checkRows();
    this.checkColumns();
    this.checkDiagonals();
}

function updateButton(id, marking) {
    let button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + marking + '.png")';
    button.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat'; // The X image is not in appropriate size.
    button.disabled = true;
    grid[Math.floor(parseInt(id)/3)][parseInt(id)%3] = marking;
        console.log(marking);
        console.log(id);

}

function getButtonPressed(id) {
    // Assuming Player 1 is marking with X.
    if (turn === 'Player_1') {
        this.updateButton(id, 'X');
        this.checkWinningPositions();
        turn = 'Player_1';
    }
    else {
        this.updateButton(id, 'O');
        this.checkWinningPositions();
        turn = 'Player_2';
    }
}

html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Tick-Tack-Toe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="left">Tick Tack Toe</h1>


        <p>Player 1: X &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Player 2: O</p>
        <!-- the tic tack toe matrix -->
        <div class = "matrix">
            <button id="0" class="button" onclick="getButtonPressed(0);"></button>
            <button id="1" class="button" onclick="getButtonPressed(1);"></button>
            <button id="2" class="button" onclick="getButtonPressed(2);"></button>
            <button id="3" class="button" onclick="getButtonPressed(3);"></button>
            <button id="4" class="button" onclick="getButtonPressed(4);"></button>
            <button id="5" class="button" onclick="getButtonPressed(5);"></button>
            <button id="6" class="button" onclick="getButtonPressed(6);"></button>
            <button id="7" class="button" onclick="getButtonPressed(7);"></button>
            <button id="8" class="button" onclick="getButtonPressed(8);"></button>
        </div>

        <script src="app.js"></script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

This code has bugs and its first time for me to fix bugs; if you cannot help me can you guide me what to do? First I notice is that it starts with X and only X. When I checked row column and diagonal it returns false. I have image X and O. I also have a CSS file just for the buttons. I believe that this grid array needs to be with 3 parts `grid[][][]` but I am still in learning, and what better way from projects I can use Stack Overflow and just by myself. So its good even if you don't have the answer to guide me how to approach the debugging. But sincerely thing that the problem lies with winning combinations.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkRows() {
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        if (grid[i][0] === grid[i+1][1] && grid[i][0] === grid[i+1][2] && grid[i][0] !== null) {
            alert(grid[i][0] === 'X' ? 'Player 1 wins!' : 'Player 2 wins!');
        }
            console.log(grid[i][0] === grid[i+1][1] && grid[i][0] === grid[i+1][2] && grid[i][0] !== null);
    }
}
```

Third row

`grid[i+1][1]`

When `i = 2`, then `i+1 = 3`

`grid[3]` is `undefined` and calling `grid[3][1]` gives an error because there are only 3 rows and not 4

---

Here is how to fix `checkRows()`

```
function checkRows() {
  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    if (grid[i][0] !== null && grid[i][0] === grid[i][1] && grid[i][0] === grid[i][2]) {
      alert(grid[0][i] === 'X' ? 'Player 1 wins!' : 'Player 2 wins!');
    }
    console.log("No alert no winner");
 }
```

}

fix columns

```
function checkColumns() {
  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
   if (grid[0][i] !== null && grid[0][i] === grid[1][i] && grid[0][i] === grid[2][i]) {
     alert(grid[i][0] === 'X' ? 'Player 1 wins!' : 'Player 2 wins!');
   }
   console.log("If there is no alert, then it means we don't have a winner");
}
```

The reason why player turn doesn't change is because you get an error, then it just stops at `this.checkWinningPosition()` and never changes the turn

EDIT 6000: I realized why you made the null check and added it back into my solutions

Comment: thank you.#Pavlo  But there are many bugs , with players turn , winning combination, etc.. If you know something that might help me also i would be greatly appriciated

Comment: I could rewrite it for you, but i don't know how much that would help

Comment: #Pavlo i like to do this as much as i can but since its first assignment, not for a company a friends of mine are teaching me. If you have the time I would be greatly appreciated, I will try my best for few weeks and if not i will see you answer

Comment: Thanks #Pavlo while you wrote the code i finished and the turns part. thank you very much

Comment: Good job mate, hopefully you will continue programming, it is more fun the more you know :)

Comment: #Pavlo thanks man i have sometimes problem with critical thinking, so is there something to send you a friend request i see you solve problems maybe github